# The best way to extend an @Entity when the subclass has just a @Transient field besides

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm

I have a superclass that is an `@Entity`, something like this one:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "utente")
public class Utente implements Serializable{
   ...
}
```

The subclass has just a `@Transient` field besides:

```
@Entity
public class UtenteSub extends Utente{
    @Transient
    private String newField;
}
```

To make it work, I should add `@DiscriminatorValue`, `@Inheritance` and add a field on the table.

This is a lot of work to do, taking into account that all I need in the subclass is just a `@Transient` field (I need it to "check" the object Utente after its "submission" in a form).

Is there a better and easier way to extend the `@Entity` in my scenario?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try creating an abstract base class UtenteBase:

```
@MappedSuperClass
public abstract class UtenteBase implements Serializable
{
   //all mapped columns go here
}
```

All your mapped columns which were in Utente before are now in this class.
You can then extend this class with your two above mentioned classes:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "utente")
public class Utente extends UtenteBase
{
   public Utente {}
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "utente")
public class UtenteSub extends UtenteBase
{
    @Transient
    private String newField;
}
```

The class Utente is the concrete implementation class and is used for the communication with the database. 
Both classes are in the same inheritance tree and you don't need to add a DiscriminatorValue and change the table.